# Based on matching key and values addition has to happen for array of objects in dataweave

Tags: dataweave

Please help on below dataweave
**Here is the Input**

```
[
  {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "100",
    "code":"ABC"
  },
  {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "200",
    "code":"ABC"
  },
   {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "200",
    "code":"CDB"
  },
  {
    "item": "12",
    "quantity": "200",
     "code":"ABC"
  }
]
```

**this is expected output**

```
[
  {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "300"
    "code":"ABC"
  },
   {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "200"
    "code":"CDB"
  },
  {
    "item": "12",
    "quantity": "200"
     "code":"ABC"
  }
]
```

Based on matching key and values addition has to happen for the array of objects.in dataweave

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with something like this..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.item ++ key.code)) mapObject {
   a: {
       item: $[0].item,
       quantity: (if (sizeOf ($)  > 1) ($.quantity reduce ($$ as Number 
                  {format: '#'} + $ as Number {format: '#'}))  else  $.quantity[0] 
                   as Number {format: "#"}),
       code:$[0].code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add pluck instead of that mapObject .. So something like

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.item ++ key.code)) pluck {
   a: {
       item: $[0].item,
       quantity: (if (sizeOf ($)  > 1) ($.quantity reduce ($$ as Number 
                  {format: '#'} + $ as Number {format: '#'}))  else  $.quantity[0] 
                   as Number {format: "#"}),
       code:$[0].code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = [
  {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "100",
    "code":"ABC"
  },
  {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "200",
    "code":"ABC"
  },
   {
    "item": "1",
    "quantity": "200",
    "code":"CDB"
  },
  {
    "item": "12",
    "quantity": "200",
     "code":"ABC"
  }
]
---
data groupBy ($.code ++ $.item) 
pluck $
reduce (e,acc=[]) -> acc + {
    item: e[0].item,
    code: e[0].code,
    quantity: sum(e.*quantity) as String
}
```